# Jquery can't hide submenu when i click on it

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu").click(function() {
    $(".almenu").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(".almenu li a").click(function() {
    $(".almenu").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.almenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu" id="furas"><a href="#">Furas</a>
      <ul class="almenu" id="furas_2">
        <li><a href="#">Mely</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kozpont</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

When i click on "Furas" menu, the submenu appears. However, if I click on any submenu it does not hide.

Could you help me to understand the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when the user clicks on the submenu it fires also the `$(".menu").click` handler (because `.menu` is its parent so it basically `click`ed too).

In order to stop this, call to [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu").click(function() {
    $(".almenu").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(".almenu li a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".almenu").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.almenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu" id="furas"><a href="#">Furas</a>
    <ul class="almenu" id="furas_2">
      <li><a href="#">Mely</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kozpont</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```